# validates_length_of :description, maximum: (not working)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have a clip model with the following validation:

```
  class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base

  DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH = 200
  validates_length_of :description, maximum: DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH

  ....
  end
```

However, when editing a description on a clip I seem to be getting a validation error even though the description only has 92 characters.

What am I doing wrong? It should be allowing descriptions of upto 200 characters in length.

**Edit (error message included):**

```
Description is too long (maximum is 200 characters)"
```

Comment: Does `Clip.create.errors` shows that the description exceed 200 caracters? My point here is that maybe the validation fails because of an another validation?

Comment: The error thrown has to do with the characters, it is: 
    "Description is too long (maximum is 200 characters)"

Comment: Does it fail no matter how many characters you enter?  Or only when you reach a number you think it shouldn't be failing at (such as 92)?

Comment: Why you can't use `validates :description, length: {maximum: 200}` ?

Comment: Still didn't work unfortunately, throwing the same error. Very strange.

Comment: Please, post your error message.

Comment: The error message is posted in the comments above, but I've added it to the post for clarity.

Comment: In addition, even when I delete all of the characters it resorts back to the original description. This might be an update issue rather than a validation issue. Something to consider.

Comment: No, not on this application.

Comment: Ok, in `rails c` create two new instances of `Clip`: 1) with `description: "a"*199`; 2) with `description: "a" * 201`. If the errors will appear in both cases - it's a problem with your model, if not - with your form/browser/controller/etc.

Comment: What type of the `description`? Check if it's a string (in your schema.rb). If it's not - that is the problem. Add new migration for changing type of it, change it to string, all should work.

Comment: The description in schema is of text type.  t.text     "description"

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do with it? Clip Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `clips` WHERE `clips`.`name` = BINARY 'test' LIMIT 1
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK

Comment: Thanks for your help @RedZagogulin, I found the solution it had to do with the Rich text editor, but I appreciate your time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods.validates_length_of is the old fashioned way of validating the length of a string. You better go with ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods.validates like:

```
    class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :description, length: { maximum: 200 }
    end
```

Both validates methods end in calling the LengthValidator.

[APIdock ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods.validates_length_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_length_of)

Btw., since the constant is only used in the validator, I wouldn't have a separate constant for the length value.

Comment: Thanks @tobago, tried this, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. It doesn't appear that the actual description text is updating. For example, when I delete 3-4 words and click save. I get the validation error (as seen above) and it resorts back to how it initially was with the 3-4 words I deleted still being there.

Comment: For further diagnose I'd need the entire model class.
Please ensure:
1.) you do not expand the description in a before_validation callback
2.) the controller action doesn't modify the description
3.) there is no Javascript event, that triggers modifying the description before submitting it

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question at all.

Answer (score -2):

So, I found the solution. I am using a rich text editor to edit the description allowing users to add styling to the actual descriptions.

However, because of this, this is what this clip has as a description:

When 2 is captured by

Therefor, the more styles you have in your description, the more characters will be added to description as html/css tags/styles

I had to make the validation 400.